# RabbitMQ crashes saying port occupied

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to open RabbitMQ for the first time so I can use celery. I am trying to run the 'rabbitmq-server' file as administrator, however this error pops up every time I press run. I saw another stackOverflow post with the same issue, however the sole comment suggested that I kill what was happening at the port.

I followed this tutorial to kill the port, however the same issue persisted. I do not know what else to try to fix this issue. Thanks for any help

https://community.talend.com/s/article/How-to-find-and-kill-a-process-running-on-a-port-LVJkZ

```
Configuring logger redirection
11:26:13.229 [warning] Using RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE: c:/Users/zoommen/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/advanced.config
11:26:15.481 [error]

11:26:15.481 [error] BOOT FAILED
BOOT FAILED
11:26:15.481 [error] ===========
===========
11:26:15.481 [error] ERROR: distribution port 25672 in use by another node: rabbit@X390-zoommen
ERROR: distribution port 25672 in use by another node: rabbit@X390-zoommen
11:26:15.481 [error]
```

Comment: It could be something that will auto re-connect it's app to that port when it's killed - you need to find out what is running on that port first and kill that application/service.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough sorry if this is a dumb question, but how would I go about finding what the specific application is

Comment: `C:\windows\system32>netstat -ano|findstr "PID :25672"
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:25672          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1508 `  This is what I see when I try and check

Comment: Rabbitmq might be already running / configured to start automatically. Have you tried using it? You could also try to restart and see what happens.
Default port is usually 5672.

Comment: @Aida when I tried to run celery, `Unable to load celery application.
The module proj was not found.` I got this error, which I think indicates it is not working ?